# Programmatically create json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

This is the JSON I'm trying to create programmatically:

```
{
    "sensors": [{
        "x": 342,
        "y": 213,
        "id": 4
    }, {
        "x": 642,
        "y": 913,
        "id": 3
    }, {
        "x": 452,
        "y": 113,
        "id": 2
    }]
}
```

I have to iterate through all elements with a specific class to retrieve the data for the json:

```
$(".marker").each(function()
{
    var x = $(this).attr("data-x");
    var y = $(this).attr("data-y");
    var id = $(this).attr("data-id");
});
```

How could I create the json object to be like I described?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this

```
var json = {"sensors":[]};

$(".marker").each(function()
{
    var x = $(this).attr("data-x");
    var y = $(this).attr("data-y");
    var id = $(this).attr("data-id");
    json.sensors.push({"x":x, "y":y,"id":id});
});
```

Comment: Bah! You beat me like a ginger step-child :) +1 Here's the fiddle I spent too long making http://jsfiddle.net/bzqZx/

Comment: ^^ ginger power! liked your answer more though, it was a lot cleaner

Answer (score -3):

Look JSON.parse method on MDN ou MSDN

```
var jsontext = '{"firstname":"Jesper","surname":"Aaberg","phone":["555-0100","555-0120"]}';
var contact = JSON.parse(jsontext);
document.write(contact.surname + ", " + contact.firstname);

// Output: Aaberg, Jesper
```